# Android: Style ActionMode on AppCompat-v7 with Toolbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar, android-actionmode

I have made a ListView with selectable items but the ActionMode is not showing properly. (There is and a "compare" menu button on the right with white color)

[image]

I tried to style the actionMode with the following code but nothing changes. Any ideas why might this happens? I found out that if I set the background color direct on the Toolbar widget instead of the DarkTheme.ActionBar the color arround the text on actionMode is gone but still the color of the text is white and also I need to have the color of the ActionBar defined on the theme instead of the widget.

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/DarkTheme.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/DarkTheme.Popup"/>
```

**mytheme.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="DarkTheme.ActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffff8800</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">#303030</item>
</style>

<style name="DarkTheme.Popup" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#101010</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">#ff0099cc</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/DarkTheme.ActionMode</item>
</style>

<style name="DarkTheme.ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">#000000</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't realy understand your stuff, it looks strange.
Theme are for Activity or Application in the manifest. For widget you should use style. 
When looking at your question, I think, you just don't know how to use theme and what themes are for.
So your theme should looks like a stuff like that:

```
    <resources>
      <style name="AppBlankTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
          <!-- Main theme colors -->
          <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
          <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
          <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
          <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
          <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
    <!--Both themes below are those accepted to make the ToolBar works-->
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBlankTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"/>
<!--The Theme for the Actvity that have actionMode-->
    <style name="ActionModeAppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then your manifest you looks like something like that:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android2ee.formation.lollipop.toolbar" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".sample.ActivityWithItems"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_with_items"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android2ee.formation.lollipop.toolbar.MainActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="com.android2ee.formation.lollipop.toolbar.EXAMPLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".sample.ActionModeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_actionmode"
            android:theme="@style/ActionModeAppTheme"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.android2ee.formation.lollipop.toolbar.MainActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="com.android2ee.formation.lollipop.toolbar.EXAMPLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And your activity looks like something like that:

```
public class ActionModeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActionMode mMode;
    /**
     * The action Bar
     */
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    Callback actionModeCallBack;
    private boolean postICS,postLollipop;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         //You could also hide the action Bar
//         getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_mode);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_custom_up);
        postICS =getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.postICS);
        postLollipop =getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.postLollipop);
        if(postLollipop){
            toolbar.setElevation(15);
        }

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        findViewById(R.id.start_actionmode).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enableActionMode();
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.stop_actionmode).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mMode != null) {
                    //To quit the ActionMode
                    mMode.finish();
                }
            }
        });


        actionModeCallBack=new  Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_mode, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(ActionModeActivity.this, "Got click: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            }
        };
    }

    private void enableActionMode() {
        mMode = startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallBack);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_with_items, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```